# Not allowed to load local resource:file:///C:/Users/

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

when I paste image from office word into html editor, IE can show the image in base-64, while chrome raise error message "Not allowed to load local resource:file:///C:/...",and can't show image. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide always the relevant snippet of your source code.

Comment: you've tagged this javascript, html and css ... show some javascript, html and css that is causing this issue

Comment: What is "html editor"?

Comment: I just use html editor named "summernote"

Comment: Same question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39007324/5610732