# Chrome loading sprites with Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, sprite, pixi.js

Chrome version 55.0.2883.95 doesn't seem to be able to load in sprites using Pixi.js. However, Firefox version 50.1.0 seems to be working just fine with the following script.

The Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="pixi.js"></script>
<script>

var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(256, 256);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

PIXI.loader.add("cat.png").load(setup);

function setup() {
  var cat = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources["cat.png"].texture);

  stage.addChild(cat);

  renderer.render(stage);
}
</script>
</body>
```

The Folder:

```
Pixi.js
cat.png
index.html
```

The Chrome Error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/cat.png may not be loaded.
    at Texture.upload (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:1911:9)
    at TextureManager.updateTexture (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:16440:27)
    at WebGLRenderer.bindTexture (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:17108:33)
    at SpriteRenderer.flush (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:21351:35)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:16896:30)
    at setup (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/index.html:18:12)
    at MiniSignal.dispatch (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:7068:18)
    at Loader._onComplete (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:5414:25)
    at file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:5451:24
    at next (file:///Users/konradwright/Desktop/SO12017/pixi.js:6610:17)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you [can't load local files asynchronously in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource) for security reasons.

Instead, you need to run a local server to serve your files.

I personally use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) module. It's very easy to use. Just install Node.js then open a command prompt. Run

```
npm install -g http-server
```

to install the http-server module. If you have permissions issues, try

```
sudo npm install -g http-server
```

After that, go to the folder where you want to serve up your website (`cd path/to/project/folder`). Run

```
http-server
```

and it will begin running a server at `http://127.0.0.1:8080` a.k.a `http://localhost:8080`. Enter that into your browser and you'll be good to go.

There are numerous other server solutions out there as well but this one takes almost no work to get it going.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Your instructions were good, and I even made a picture tutorial of it. However, I ran into a snag. The instructions failed to complete the task asked of them. Could you review it for me? http://imgur.com/a/xIntM

Comment: @KonradWright Looks like a typical permissions error to me. Try `sudo npm install -g http-server`.

Comment: Thank you Mike! Could you update your answer to reflect the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that may work is "Web Server for Chrome" app. You start it up, choose the folder wishing to work with and go to URL (like 127.0.0.1:port you chose)

It is a simple server and cannot use PHP but for simple work, might be your solution:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb