# <img> tag is not working in php Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

`<img>` tag is not working in `PHP Codeigniter`

`<img src="<?php echo $p_info['p_img']; ?>" alt="Product Image is not uploaded" height="700px" width="500px" />`

Output of `$p_info['p_img']` is giving correct path where image is saved.
and i uploaded the image now i want to show that image in edit process

Comment: No idea what "edit process" is. Can you maybe post some more code of what you've attempted to do and give a detailed explanation on why it isn't working?

Comment: Mayeb give the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve a read

Comment: whats in `<?php echo $p_info['p_img']; ?>`, show the data

Comment: try to add base url, directory name and then image name

Comment: So your rendered html doesn't show the image? Maybe it's not accessable for the browser, check the developer console for http errors.

Comment: Do you get absolute path(Full path) or relative path on output of $p_info['p_img']?

Comment: edit process is editing product details nothing is wrong with it.
i just want to show this image in the edit view. where every field is editable which was submitted . but image is not showing. @IsThisJavascript

Comment: $p_info['p_img']? give the exact path where my images is saved..
here is output 
C:/xampp/htdocs/squadfreetry/assests/img/products_images/Acne Free (1).jpg

Comment: Try `src ="<?=base_url();?>/assests/img/products_images/Acne Free (1).jpg"`

Comment: @AndreasWeswaldi  you are right i got this error in concole
Not allowed to load local resource:
please give answer how to solve this error

Comment: @Sinto whole path is saved in the database. which i will correct later.
but now image should be shown.
I have different images for different products.

Comment: You donot have to save `C:/xampp/htdocs/`. Just try now by directly giving link to image.

Comment: @Sinto i try your code it is showing image. but every product have different image so i cannot simply add this code.
because it will show same image for every different product

Comment: yeah I got that mistake ..
now I'm solving this ..
Thanks every one for the help

Comment: So you have to save the path as starting from your project directory not your local path as you did.

Comment: Does your `$p_info['p_img']` starts with 'file://'? Then you are referencing to a local file, which is not allowed in several browsers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Comment: Does the issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo $p_info['p_img']; ?>" 
alt="Product Image is not uploaded" height="700px" width="500px" />
```

`<?php echo $p_info['p_img']; ?>` should be a path which access images from the project directory not from a local path.

`C:/xampp/htdocs/squadfreetry/assests/img/products_images/Acne Free (1).jpg` this is wrong & will not show image.

You have to save image path starting from `/assests/...` and to access it by calling `base_url()` at first & followed by saved path in DB.

Code should be like:

```
<img src="<?=base_url().$p_info['p_img'];?>" 
alt="Product Image is not uploaded" height="700px" width="500px" />
```

Where `$p_info['p_img']` is a path starting from `/assests/..`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you view source using certain browsers (firefox, chrome), it omits the /> tag. Try view source using a notepad or something, it should display proper /> tag.

If you want a shorter tag, use this:

```
 <?php echo img(array('src'=>'image/picture.jpg', 'alt'=> 'alt information')); ?>
```

Here is detailed information:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img

**More examples:**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/uploads/' . $gambar)?>" alt=""/>
```

and

```
<img src='<?php echo base_url("assets/uploads/$gambar")?>' alt=""/>
```

Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below way:

I am assuming that your project folder is Cart -> images/your desired image

when you do file uploading then you have to save the image in folder -> images
and the image name in database.

so to access it replace your image code like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/<?php echo $p_info['p_img']; ?>" alt="Product Image is not uploaded" height="700px" width="500px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On CodeIgniter 4 you can use the img function, from html helper.

1. Adds the helper on controller -> `helper('html')`;
2. Generates the img tag on the view -> `echo img('public/img.png')`.