# Not allowed to load local resource [Vue js with Axios]

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I get the path of the file using Axios.get : 
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\lorem.csv`

Axios syntax get

```
{
    // axios post generate
    const URL = '/api/report'+ '/generate'
    axios.post(URL, {
      report: this.editedItem.report,
      values: this.editedItem.values
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.fetchItem()
        const URL = '/api/report/path'
        axios.get(URL)
          .then(response => {
            this.path = response.data
          })
          .catch(err => {
            alert(err)
          })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        //what happen after error
        alert(err)
      })
    this.close()
  }
```

And I send that path to the a tag

```
<a :href="path" download target="_blank" class="tabs__item tabs__item--active" style="position: relative;"><u>{{ path }}</u></a>
```

> but, console says : Not allowed to load local resource: [path]

I've tried [doesn't work]:
 - node: __dirname: false, __filename: false
 - blob type data
 - other browser, still same

The file is dynamic, server produce the file and save the file in the directory.

Comment: Maybe try using `vue-axois` instead?

Comment: @MonkeyOnARock i'm using it.

Comment: @NadyaPrabaningrum your not using the `vue-axios` library. the `vue-axios` lib would start out with `this.$http` or `this.axios`. But this is irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Comment: if I'm not using axios, I can't get the path from api @TrevorVarwig

Comment: @NadyaPrabaningrum If I've answered your question from which you comments I think I have you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4):

You're using Axios as a frontend library, which means that it doesn't get access to the file system. `Not allowed to load local resource:` This is telling you that you're trying to break the sandbox that is in the browser.

Axios is specfically for calling api's though you can use it on things like `Node` that do have access to the file system with something like `fs` which is why you can still attempt to do this when  using it in the browser.

Comment: what should I do :( I wanna get the file from the path that I got

Comment: Well you could serve it directly from the static files in your vue project using require that would be an option I suppose. The other option is to host the file somewhere and serve a link to the file instead.

Comment: unfortunately, the file is dynamic

Comment: @NadyaPrabaningrum Then you'll have to consider serving it from an external server instead and requesting the generated link using an API most likely.

Comment: If your generating the file on the server-side what's stopping you from making it available from there and providing a link to the available document on the server which you can use in your vue app?