# Download local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angular

**Html File**

```
<button mat-button (click) = "FileDownload">Download</button>
```

**Anugular 4 Component Method**

```
FileDownload()
{
  this.filePath = "D:\SamplePDF.pdf";
  document.loation.href = this.filePath;

}
```

Here, I want to download the local file when button click happens. I am not able to download the file. Please help.

PS: I am not able to access window.open() also as I am using angular 4 application.

Comment: `file:///d:/SamplePDF.pdf`?

Comment: @john, I am getting this error in console: Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: Then it's not possible because of the security settings of your browser. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this snippet

```js
function downloadFunc(){
     var anchor=document.createElement('a');
     anchor.setAttribute('href','D:/SamplePDF.pdf');
     anchor.setAttribute('download','');
     document.body.appendChild(anchor);
     anchor.click();
     anchor.parentNode.removeChild(anchor);
  }
```

Comment: I have used your code but getting the same error in console: Not allowed to load local resource.

Comment: btw I have tried different approach using https://gist.github.com/liabru/11263260

Comment: "Not allowed to load local resource" Local file and Server are different that the time get that issue.

Other wise you have try convert local file into blob data and then set anchor element it will might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do like this.

```
<a href="your_link" download> file_name </a>
```

Use a tag instead of button and implement material button style there.
And use `download` attribute to implement the download action.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
/**
 * Method is use to download file.
 * @param data - Array Buffer data
 * @param type - type of the document.
 */
downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: What is Blob? Do we need to install any package?

Comment: please refer this --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Thanks, but how to convert the file to data?

Comment: whatever the file/data  and type of file u have just pass it to 'downLoadFile(data: any, type: string)'.

Answer (score 0):

¿Are you using ngnix or apache? You can force download with ngnix or apache by sending the content as an "attachment" (using "Content-Disposition" header).

This is a sample config to do this with Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    location ~ ^.*/(?P<request_basename>[^/]+\.(pdf))$ {
        root /path/to/pdf/
        add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$request_basename"';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

**javascript**:

```
window.open('file:///c://Documents/folder/file.ext', 'Download');
```

**html**:

```
<a href="file:///C://Documents/folder/file.ext">Download Me</a>
```

Comment: I am not able to access window.open. I am using Angular 4 application. Any Idea?