# How do I restart or kill Google Chrome using vanilla JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can't use,

```
window.location = 'chrome://restart';
```

Because then I get this error message:

> "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://restart/"

So what do I do to restart or kill Google Chrome using vanilla Javascript?

Comment: That sounds like the sort of thing that definitely shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Comment: a web page does not (and should not) have any such access

Comment: @31piy Flagged because it's not a possible duplicate.

Comment: @NisargShah `chrome://` pages are a "local resource"

Comment: I'm so glad there's no way of killing Google chrome using JavaScript.

Comment: @JaromandaX Not only do the answers fail to specifically address why that's not allowed, but this question is asking "How to restart chrome?", not "How to access chrome://restart".

Comment: @NisargShah -- 1) It is flagged as _possible duplicate_, not _exact duplicate_. If others think that it is exact duplicate, this would have been closed already. 2) I flagged it because _I think_ that it is related to the target question. It is not necessary that I am right, but I tried to search for the problem and found the target question as a suitable candidate.

Comment: @NisargShah - sure, that's your opinion, I happen to disagree

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for local browser to be restarted by JavaScript running in that browser if we have following configuration:

- local server running on some port, say 12345, localhost:12345
- this server can accept some API requests, say GET /restart, http://localhost:12345/restart
- on GET /restart handler our server executes script that kills/re-runs local Browser processes, something like `sudo service chrome-remote-desktop restart` (follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/131019/killing-all-instances-of-chrome-on-the-command-line), [that](https://superuser.com/questions/1205694/how-to-restart-chrome-remote-desktop-from-command-line) etc)

Than you need to make an API call to your server from your local browser script with for example `fetch`...

Comment: Still, not possible with _vanilla JavaScript code_, which OP has asked.

Comment: I understand, but let the OP to have a chance to take a bit broader view of the situation.