# How to open a file from local drive - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angular

I am trying to open the file available in local drive directly using the angular application with whatever the editor the system is associated with.

**Html**

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Desert.jpg">  
<span  (click)="openFile(parameter)">Open file</span></a>
```

I have also tried using the below approach with no help.

```
window.open("file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Desert.jpg")
```

But I am getting the following error message in browser console:

- **Not allowed to access local resource**

I understand that we cannot directly access the local drive files directly using the angular application.

Is there any way round to open any type of file(like jpg, docx, txt, etc)?

I know its a common issue and definitely, your answers will help lot of people.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Include them in your angular application's assets; or 2) serve the files from a local or remote web server.

Comment: Host the file on a web server and ajax it. Under normal conditions, jaavscript has no programmatical  access to the users hard drive. Imagine what kind of malice could be done if it was possible.

Comment: i think you are using chrome may be [chrome local file security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46480984/2417602) will help

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? i am stuck in the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

you can load files from the client machine using `Javascript FileReader object`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `<input id="preview" type="file" (change)="previewFile($event)" />`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  public previewImage(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      console.log('csv content', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome then chrome specifically blocks local file access this way for security reasons.

there is a workaround for this that can be found here [How to set the allow-file-access-from-files flag option in Google Chrome](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of Barr J, it's due to the security reason of Chrome.

I used a simple [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) serve server "Web Server for Chrome".

You choose the folder (C:\images) and launch the server on your desired port.
Now access your local file by:

```
function run(){
   var URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8887/image.jpg";    
   window.open(URL, null);    
}
run();
```