# Asp.net Core File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

when i save image, image save successfully in database, but it takes full image path like this C:\Users....\Uploads\employee.jpg i dont want like this, i need to save image path somehting like this ~Uploads\employee.jpg and in specific folder and same path should save in database, also if someone show me after saving correct path how i can view that image. there is error i get because of this:

"Not allowed to load local resource :file:///C:/......"

thank you!

my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Photos photos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var filePath = 
            Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
            "Uploads", photos.FormFile.FileName);
            photos.PhotoPath = filePath;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await photos.FormFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            _context.Add(photos);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["NewsId"] = new SelectList(_context.News, "NewsId", 
        "NewsBigTitle", photos.NewsId);
        return View(photos);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Break the code down:

`var localPath = Path.Combine("Upload", "file.jpg");`

`var fullPath = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.ContentRootPath, localPath);`

Save the `localPath` to `PhotoPath`

**Edit**

Okey so now bring up your `PhotoPath` in a View, and make it target a file stream action.

```
[HttpGet("path/{image}")]
public FileStreamResult Image(string image)
{
    var result = new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(
                  Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.ContentRootPath, image),
                  FileMode.Open,
                  FileAccess.Read), "image/<your_mime>");
    return result;
}
```

The best way I think is to create a new string in the following format `http://example.com/path/image.jpg` and bind it to `src`.

**You can't target dynamically added files by using the following: `~/path/image.jpg` for your source.**

Comment: hi ,this did not help ,still getting this ,still getting full path  :Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/rustam/Desktop/FightSports-backend/FightSports/Uploads/unnamed.jpg

Comment: @rustam13 Updated the answer

Comment: sorry.i did not inderstand ,you mean to path my filePath string into this method ?can you explain please

Comment: i fixed it with this line of code :photos.PhotoPath = Path.GetFileName(photos.FormFile.FileName);  thanks for help

Comment: @rustam13 don't use `FileName` property of the File to save your file, it will cause issues when uploading in IE, and don't forget to mark the question answered if you think this answers your question.

Comment: thank you, but i cant mark question, i have not enough reputaion

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured `IFileProvider` pointing to your `Uploads` folder in `Configure` method of `Startup` class:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // Default one

// Adding one more location - folder named `Uploads` to be a custom static files folder. 
// The `Uploads` folder is available in the content root directory of the application (where your `Controllers` folder. 
// You can point it of course inside `wwwroot` - use `env.WebRootPath` instead)

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Uploads")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Uploads")
});
```

Once you do this you should be able to upload the file this way in your controller action:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads", photos.FormFile.FileName);

using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    await photos.FormFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: hi,i did that ,still geting this , still getting full path : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/rustam/Desktop/FightSports-backend/FightSports/Uploads/unnamed.jpg

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource