# Angular 5 problem with Chrome and the "Not Allowed to open local resource"

Tags: c#, angular, file, google-chrome

So I got an application for a client that has a lot of files that need to be opened from within the application, pdf files mostly. I got everything working but when I tried to open the link:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" tooltip="Ver" href="{{ file.fileLocation }}" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

It gives me the "Not Allowed to open local resource: file://srvnas/files/architecture_map.pdf" error, I know this is a Chrome security feature, I want to know what is the most efficient way to open this files. My backend works with asp.net core 2.1 and web api. Do I need to do some kind of fileserver? Do I need to open the files in another way? This folder I try to access is an open folder that is accessible to everyone so the security issue is not a problem to be honest.

Any points in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to take in consideration here when the user visits your website he/she makes the request to your web server

The web server will send the files to the client (HTML, CSS, JS)

**So same as you have to send PDF file to the client.**

If it's static files you can simply host them on the server and point the client to it.

E.g

> Location on server

```
https://example.com/data/MyPdf.pdf
```

Link On Client side

```
<a class="btn btn-info" tooltip="Ver" href="example.com/data/MyPdf.pdf" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

**And if you have dynamic content you have to set up an API Endpoint which serves PDF content**

IN order to get a link from API

you should return location from your API

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetPdfLink(int id)
{
    return new {Data="Path To Your PDF From DB"};
}
```

**In your Angular Service extract Data property from response object and set it to your href**

Comment: I have dynamic content, the link is pulled from the db where we store the file location. Do you have any directions for setting up an API endpoint?