# It's posible print PDF when PDF is open in memorystream?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, printing

Its posible open print dialog when is open in memorystram?
Actually I   save the pdf in **"~/App_Data/Rep_PDF/"** and after show a pdf in an iframe but I cant do it because I recive a message :

**"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/andres.martinez/Documents/TFS%20Monterrey%20Gob/InterfaceMonterrey%20PROD/Interface%20Monterrey%20PROD/InterfaceMonterrey/App_Data/Rep_PDF/Copia_C_Administrativa%2030-04-2019.pdf"**

Could you help me How to print a pdf in asp mvc?

this is part of my code:

```
 public ActionResult ImprimeReporte()
    {
        //Indicamos donde vamos a guardar el documento
        string directorioRaiz = "~/App_Data/Rep_PDF/";
        string NombreArchivoPDF = "C_Administrativa " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".pdf";
        string path_Original=Server.MapPath(directorioRaiz+NombreArchivoPDF);
        string path_Copia = Server.MapPath(directorioRaiz + "Copia_"+NombreArchivoPDF);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path_Original))
        {
            //SI EXISTE EL ARCHIVO EN LA CARPETA, LO MANDA A IMPRIMIR
            Inicia_PrintScript(path_Original, path_Copia);
            ViewData["path_Copia"] = path_Copia;
            //Elimina los archivos , despues de que se imprimio
            // System.IO.File.Delete(path_Original);
            //System.IO.File.Delete(path_Copia);
        }
        else
        {
            //SI NO EXISTE MANDA LLAMAR AL METODO PARA DESCARGAR EL ARCHIVO Y DESPUES IMPRIMIRLO
            Genera_Pdf_Administrativo();
            Inicia_PrintScript(path_Original, path_Copia);
            ViewData["path_Copia"] = path_Copia;
            //Elimina los archivos , despues de que se imprimio
            //System.IO.File.Delete(path_Original);
            //System.IO.File.Delete(path_Copia);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

second part

```
public static void Inicia_PrintScript(string Original, string Copia)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Original);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(Copia, FileMode.Create));
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
        stamper.JavaScript = "this.print(true);\r";
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

View

```html
<iframe src="@ViewData["path_Copia"].ToString()" id="myFrame" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" width="700" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Comment: You're trying to load a local resource. That won't work at all once deployed at the server. You need to route the PDF through a controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's possible to open a PDF with print dialog in another tab.

In your controller you need to get the file in memory just to return it, or generate the file on fly.

```
public FileResult PDFToReturn()
{
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("Path_to_PDF");
    return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filePath));
}
```

javascript does the magic.

```
function printPDF() {
    let link = 'javascript:w=window.open("/Controller/PDFToReturn"); w.print();';
    location.href = link;
}
```