# Not allowed to load local resource in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a basic problem I think this is a common question but I could not find a solution for this. I could not load image from local system :

```
<img src="file://///C:\Users\Pictures\Screenshots\123.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

I have this error:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/Users/Pictures/Screenshots/123.png

Comment: This should be expected behavior.

Comment: Add images to assets

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, the access of files that are located outside of the project folder is not allowed. You should most probably place it inside there for most of the cases. If you still want to do it, you can find some workaround(s) consulting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource) answer.