# Image display on a local host by retrieving its local path stored in a MySQL database through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hey I am trying to display an image whose local link is saved in MySQL database. I am writing a SQL query to select the required local link which is further stored in a variable to be passed to HTML image display function. The problem is that image is not being displayed rather short square containing cross symbol is being displayed.

// skipping the coding in which SQL connection is made and php script starting syntax

```
   <?php

   $sql = "SELECT locallink FROM timetable WHERE id=6";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $a = $row["locallink"];
    }
    }else {
     echo "0 results";
          }
   ?> 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <img src="<?php echo $a ?>" alt="Section A timetable">


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think you haven't close the php tag after `echo "0 results"`

Comment: What is the value of `$a`

Comment: The fetched local link is being stored in $a

Comment: you should close the php scope after echo 0 results.

Comment: And yes I did close the php tag in the actual code.

Comment: It's just I did not add it here\

Comment: also you have to get the image from the directory where stored the image with the stored name.

Comment: you write your image code in else part.where is the closing bracket for else?

Comment: I did place closing bracket for else, just missed in typing here.  And it is now edited, Thanks.

Comment: "_The fetched local link is being stored in $a_" And what is _the value_ of `$a`? Have you taken a look at the source code to make sure it is a valid image url? On your server? Does the file exist? What happens when you paste the URL of `$a` in your browser's addressbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some issues with your code so I decided to make some modifications for you to review. If you are getting results back the below should work.

If you would be able to provide an example of `locallink` that would be helpful. You may also need to append `"file:///"` to the output of the `$image` variable.

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT locallink FROM timetable WHERE id=6";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    /*
     * Output the data from each row into a array to form a collection. If 
     * we don't do this you will only end up with the last result in the while
     * loop.
     */
    $a = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $a[] = $row["locallink"];
    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

/**
 * OutputImages
 * 
 * This function will take a collection of image locations and return a HTML 
 * markup string to the output buffer.
 * 
 * @param type array $images This should be an associative array.
 */
function OutputImages($images) {
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Section A timetable">';
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        /*
         * Now if we made it this far we can assume we have a collection of images
         * that we want to display. We can now call the OutputImages function.
         */
        OutputImages($a);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If u are running your server on local machine, then it won't be displayed as chrome not allow local resources to load

you may get helep from

[Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Comment: I am running it on Microsoft Edge.