# ASPNET image can't show in chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I have the remote computer, it name is A11
and a image file name is A22

i try my code use aspnet run IE11 , IE11 can show image ,but chrome can't show.

my code is same , as follow

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image2.ImageUrl = @"file://A11/A2222.jpg";
    Image1.ImageUrl = @"\\A11\\A2222.jpg";
}
```

i try other method

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\A11\\A2222.jpg");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;Filename=" + @"\\A11\\A2222.jpg");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.ToString());
```

other method:
 clear Cache 
 open image display option

but it is not working for chrome, it still no show my image

how can i do ?

ps.

chrome ver.78.0.3904.108

Comment: Open developer tools in chrome ctrl+shift+i, goto console tab and check for errors, then goto network tab, reload the page and look for the image download.

Comment: Thanks,this method is very useful, I successfully solved my problem.

Comment: as follow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern browsers doesn't allow local images to be shown unless you open a static html file from local disk. Since you are using asp.net webforms I will assume you are not doing this and you might need to rethink your approach.

If you simply need to be able to use images from a fileshare I would instead make a virtual directory on IIS and use this instead, so links becomes /virtualdirectory/somefile.jpg for example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing , i trie this method ,it can do!!