# How to Add a Script in column of sharepoint list / document library

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, sharepoint-online

I need a code in sharepoint online, that triggers a script to open a file, where the location of file in local computer.  In my opinion, this code like button/image/hyperlink/etc, in the background is Javascript/JQUERY (event click) and this button will be placed in a specific column (in the example below the name of column is "FileLocation") in sharepoint list / sharepoint document library. like screen shoot below.

[image: My SharePoint Online List]

Answer (score 0):

You can insert JS/Jquery script or change the Dom elements on the field through [SPFx Field extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer).

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/js-field-weather/src/extensions/weather/WeatherFieldCustomizer.ts

And you can open lcoal file using js as below:

- https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/js+openfile+inside+html

Besides, some browsers will specifically block local file access this way for security reasons.

- [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

BR

Comment: thakns for your answers.

i will try .