# Can't display a PDF | file:// + href + IP Server + Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, iframe, href

I'm trying to display a PDF but it's impossible.

The only thing that the console returns is this :
*Not allowed to load local resource: file://XX.XXX.XX.XX/folder/mypdf.pdf*

Here's my code :

```html
<a href='file:\\\\XX.XXX.XX.XX\\folder\\mypdf.pdf'>Click to see the PDF</a>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Comment: I'm not using a local server actually

Comment: Well, yeah, that is why you are getting the error message …

Comment: So if I don't use a local server, I'm gonna have a "Not allowed to load local resource" ?
I mean, nothing is "local", the PDF is not local

Comment: `file://` in itself means “local” to the browser, it is a pseudo protocol for accessing file systems. Whether you try to use that to access some mapped network drive or whatever, doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: Well, maybe, but it doesn't tell me (even in the following link) how to counter that

Comment: It already tells you that you have the option to start a browser like Chrome with a flag (if you need this in a local environment you have control over only), or that you will need to proxy the file through some kind of HTTP server instead. And if neither of those are viable options for you - well, a simple “what you want is not possible” sometime just _is_ the answer.