# How can I open empty default new tabs in chromuim based browsers?

Tags: javascript

I want a javascript instruction that will allow me to open a new default (empty) browser tab,
So far I've tried this `window.open('chrome://newtab', '_blank');`
But the browser returns the following error, `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://newtab/`, even when serving the code with a local server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Comment: I pointed out that I have served the code using a local server, still get the same error though, so that didn't solve it

Answer (score 2):

The thing is you **cannot load local resources**.
This is also true for `chrome://settings/`
since Chrome doesn't want to let websites trick inexperienced users into changing the settings.

I'm sure you have already tried this but the closest alternative is loading an `about:blank` tab with `window.open("");`

Or, since most of the users have a search engine in their new tab, you can just load `window.open("https://www.google.com/");`.

The bottom line is You can't load anything that starts with `chrome://`

Comment: thing is, I am only interested in opening the browser native new tab, but guess it ain't possible after all

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to open a `chrome://` tab because that is a security risk, so the browser restricts it. It is also not the best solution since it only works on Chrome. Instead, you should open `about:blank`.

```
window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
```

Comment: I'm currently only targeting chrome, I'm well aware of the code snippet you've suggested, Only that doesn't actually open a default new tab. Is there any way I can bypass this security restriction ?

Comment: @DamilaWhiShadow If you are only targeting Chrome, does that mean that you are writing an extension?

Comment: You could say that, but for now I'm only trying to accomplish the action in question