# Not allowed to load local resources Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, file, google-chrome

I have an angular app. When I try to open a text file from a new window in a local folder(F drive) on button click, console log the below error. Any suggestion to fix this and open it.

```
 clickme(){
    window.open("F:/Angular repo/New Text Document.txt", "_blank");                           
     }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Comment: Thanks @Jax-p this didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

you cannot open such a file from a web page that is hosted on a "server" (wether your Angular app is served with ng serve command or with a web server like nginx).
You would need to upload it somewhere, and it will have an URL on its own :

```
- http://my-server/my-file.txt
```

Or you can place this file in the /assets folder of your Angular application, if you intend to deliver this file along with your Angular pages.

Maybe you can check such articles about assets in Angular :
https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/03/angular-cli-different-ways-to-include-assets/

Cheers

Comment: any workaround to make the local folders accessible?

Comment: Well, this is not related to Angular really, so I would advice you to check on your objectives, what exactly do you want to do with this file, does it really have to be on the disk ... and so on. If you really want to access it, you would have to make a input type file in HTML form and use the FileAPI to read it eventually.  https://web.dev/read-files/