# Open File URL in new Tab with React-router-dom Link

Tags: reactjs, file, url, react-router, hyperlink

I've created a dynamic file search URL that returns the file URL in the `{row}` form. And I've been trying to add the functionality to open the same file URL in a new tab on click.

Here `{row}` returns the full file path from the Device's directory which is, in my case,
`/users/prerak/Desktop/OpenMFRefer/data/message1`

I've tried -

`` <Link to={`${row}`} target="_blank">{row}</Link> ``

But this redirects me to `localhost:3000/<file path>`. Instead, it should redirect me to `file:///<file path>`

I also tried -
`` <Link to={`/${row}`} target="_blank">{row}</Link> ``
which sends me to `http://<file Path>` which is pretty much more of the same issue.

Please tell me how I can fix this.

Comment: Opening file URLs directly is a [security risk](https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/). Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46480984/10538100) which describes how to setup a local server to serve specific files without needing the `file://` URL.

Comment: try adding **//** before path or url i.e`to={'//${row}'}` to remove localhost from the url.

Comment: Thanks for the Help and solutions. But the ```{'//${row}'}``` didn't work as It's still considered as a security concern. Is there any other workaround which I can implement without using any new packages?