# Why is jquery file not loading with <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have an Angular project where I am trying to load jquery in the `index.html` file. Rather than loading it directly from the jquery website like this: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`, I am downloading and saving the jquery file in the same directory as the `index.html` file and loading it like this: `<script src="./jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`. But it's not working, because when I open chrome browser console and type in `$().jquery`, it's saying:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jquery') at <anonymous>:1:4`

But if I load jquery from the jquery url like this:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`, then it works.

The network tab says the jquery file is "(blocked:other)" in red wording.

The dev console says:

`Not allowed to load local resource: (my absolute path to the jquery file on my laptop)`

Comment: Remember that "it's not working" does tell people anything. What _does_ it do? What does your dev tools "network" tab say? Is it a 404? Is it a 200? What does the dev console say when you set it to show "all"? Are there any load error notifications? Also, why do you have a `<base>` element? (and are you making sure that your relative links actually make sense, given that base?)

Comment: There are several way to use jquery in Angular ,you may refer to the following page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The network tab says the jquery file is "(blocked:other)" in red wording. The dev console says the message I posted in the original question.

Comment: In the Angular framework, we recommend not manipulating the DOM directly, so in many situations, you needn't use jquery.

Comment: Is your page url 'file:\\' - ie are you opening the files directly into the browser or are the served from a localhost server?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Dev console also says, "Not allowed to load local resource: (my absolute path to the jquery file on my laptop)"

Comment: @freedomn-m Right now the jquery file is saved on my laptop in a folder.

Comment: You can only run js from a webserver, not from local files.   First result for "not allowed to load local resource" gives you the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Comment: @Kingamere remember to not tell "me", [tell everyone](/help/how-to-ask) by updating your post with the details that were missing. Show the exact errors you're seeing (by copy-pasting them, not with screenshots)

Comment: I agree with @TheKNVB. You should choose between jQuery and Angular (or even React), don't use both. What's the point?

Comment: We have to use Jquery in our project. Not my decision.

Comment: @freedomn-m We are trying to load an old application built using jquery into our angular project. So our angular project needs to import jquery file.

Comment: Regardless - you're not here to be preached at - it sounds like your issue is that you're not using a webserver to provide your files - that's what the error message is saying at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your files in a folder:

```
/someFolder
    - index.html
    - jquery.js
```

If you just load the HTML file in a browser, referencing the JS file in the same folder, then you're trying to load a "local resource".

You can tell by looking in the browser's location (URL) bar:

- `file://` is loading a local file into the browser.
- `http://` or `https://` is loading a file from a web server.

If you want to properly test your HTML file loading a JS file from your local machine, then you need to run a web server locally as well.

Then you should be loading your file in the browser like `http://localhost/index.html`.